# Conformal map from $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ to the open unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a conformal/analytic map from $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ to the open unit disk?

I think the answer is no but I'm not sure how to prove it. I know that the former is not simply connected and the latter is simply-connected, but I'm not sure why this is useful or relevant since analytic maps are not necessarily homeomorphisms.

Comment: Suppose one existed from the disk to the punctured plane. Draw a circle around zero in the punctured plane. The inverse image of this circle should be some closed curve in the disc. Now the argument principle applied to the conformal map along this curve should show that conformal map has a zero, which should be impossible since zero is not in it’s range.

Answer (score 9):

There's the constant map ...

Otherwise a holomorphic $f:\Bbb C-\{0\}\to D$ is bounded, so has
a removable singularity at $0$, so is a restriction of
a holomorphic $g:\Bbb C\to D$. Now apply Liouville.

Comment: I like this better than what my comment was suggesting

Comment: I see. (of course I meant "onto" the unit disk)

Comment: @user1488 Another argument. Take $f$ as above, and apply Liouville to $h(z)=f(\exp(z))$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Why does $f$ being bounded imply it has a removable singularity at $0$?

Comment: @AlJebr That's a standard theorem in complex analysis.